# Failed to create armhf machine on LXD

Tags: virtualization, lxd

I am trying to make ubuntu 16 armhf machine on ubuntu 16 64 host machine. I tried withafter installing qemu-user-static packages.

Running this command

```
lxc launch images:ubuntu/xenial/armhf blaharmhf1
```

Gave this error

```
Creating blaharm1d
error: Failed container creation:
 - https://images.linuxcontainers.org: Requested architecture isn't supported by this host
```

How to run armhf container on ubuntu 16? Is lxc the correct tool in the first place or I should use KVM or similar tool?

Answer (score 0):

Containers aren't virtualisation or emulation, if you are looking to run an armhf image you might be better off looking at QEMU and installing the Ubuntu armhf image onto that.

Comment: but as far as I know, lxc already uses qemu for emulation.